# PHPExcel How to write formula without calculating the result

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a `xls` with two sheets, and I'm trying to build a stats sheet. However, some formulas require functions that are not yet implemented by [phpexcel](/questions/tagged/phpexcel), and I don't really mind as long as it's calculated when I open the file in Excel.

```
$sheet->setCellValue('B2', '=COUNTIF(Adjoints!A:A, "<>")');
$sheet->setCellValue('C2', '=COUNTIFS(Adjoints!B:B,"=No",Adjoints!C:C,"=No")');
```

When I try to save, I get an exception:

> Invalid cell coordinate A

Because the range `A:A` is not yet implemented. Therefore, I disabled the pre-calculation on save.

```
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Excel5');
$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
$writer->save('export.xls');
```

No exception is thrown, but both of my cells (`B2` and `C2`) are empty.
When I copy paste my formula in the respective cell, Excel is able to find the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPExcel may not be calculating the formula; but it still has to be parsed to store it in BIFF-format xls files (xlsx using the Excel2007 stores the formula in a different manner that doesn't require parsing).

So I'd suggest saving the file as xlsx (using the Excel2007 Writer) and see if that works